# QR Code with extra payload via steganography

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, qr-code, steganography

I'm trying to use the approach described on [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8985346) to "watermark" a QR Code with a special payload.

The whole flow seems to be correct, but I'm having some trouble saving the payload as bytes to be xor'd against the QR Code

```py
import qrcode
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=5,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
    box_size=10,
    border=2,
)

msg = "25.61795.?000001?.907363.02"
sct = "secret message test"


def save_qrcode(data, path):
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    img.save(path)


save_qrcode(msg, "out.png")
save_qrcode(sct, "out2.png")
pure_qr_code = Image.open("out.png")

encoded_data_as_img = Image.new(mode=pure_qr_code.mode, size=pure_qr_code.size)
encoded_data_pre_xor = [ord(e) for e in sct]
print(encoded_data_pre_xor)

# Encoding
encoded_data_as_img.putdata(encoded_data_pre_xor)
encoded_data_as_img.save("out2.png")
encoded_data_as_img = Image.open("out2.png")
result = ImageChops.logical_xor(pure_qr_code, encoded_data_as_img)
result.save("result.png")

# Decoding
result = Image.open("result.png")
result2 = ImageChops.logical_xor(result, pure_qr_code)
result2.save("result2.png")
img_data_as_bytes = Image.open("result2.png").getdata()

encoded_data_after_xor = []
i = 0
while img_data_as_bytes[i]:
    encoded_data_after_xor.append(img_data_as_bytes[i])
    i += 1
print(encoded_data_after_xor)
```

This gives me the following output:

```py
[115, 101, 99, 114, 101, 116, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116]
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
```

But trying to diff `result2.png` and `out2.png` returns a no-diff. This means the problem happens on the message to image saving

```py
encoded_data_as_img.putdata(encoded_data_pre_xor)
```

Comment: I am confused: The whole point of this technique is so that someone who gets their hands on the QR code file won’t even know that it contains a hidden message. But if they are suspicious that it might, they would try to decode it. The decoding process will reveal the public message but only after applying error detection and correction. **But there shouldn’t be *any* errors in the file.** That correction was required alone indicates that there is a hidden payload. Is this not correct?

Comment: @Booboo you are correct.  The answer that the OP posted is incorrect even with ChatGPT's assistance.  The paper that the OP provided talks about using steganography coupled with cryptography to hide a message in a QR code without changes the public message for the QR code or the image itself.  It is also is suppose to resist steganalysis attacks, which the OP's answer output doesn't.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I am still missing something,: What is not made explicit (unless I missed it) is how the QR Code is "transmitted" to the "decoder", the two possibilities being (1) a *printed* image is sent or (2) The QR Code file itself is sent. If the former, there could potentially be errors in the image beyond those introduced by the inclusion of the hidden payload. In this case I would think it impossible to recover the hidden payload. If the latter, which makes sense to me, then no error correction would be required if there is no hidden payload and error correction required otherwise.

Comment: @Booboo How the QR Code is "transmitted" to the intended "decoder" is vague in the paper.  Based on my knowledge of steganography the "decoder" would require the QR code in an electronic format.  The research paper talks about printing the image, but the paper isn't clear on how any encoded message can be extracted from a printed image.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I would think decoding of the hidden payload possible only if one is processing the actual image file.  Then each box of the code should be either all white or all black. If this is not the case or if error correction must be used to read the public message, there must be a hidden payload. But my assumptions must be wrong because the research paper says its method works.  It's interesting but unexplained that the image dimension N must be such that `N = 17 * 4x` for some x (an *odd* number). A reference implementation would have been a  nice addition obviating the OP's question.

Comment: @Booboo the  N = 17 * 4x dimension stuff seems to come from the QR v2 standard.

Comment: @Booboo the OP's implementation from the paper is incorrect, because they need both images to extract the secret message, which is contained in the first 16 bytes of the secret message image file.   This is the message, _\x8b\x97\x96\x8c\xdf\x96\x8c\xdf\x9e\xdf\x8c\x9a\x9c\x8d\x9a\x8b_, which stands out when you extract the numpy array info.

Comment: @Booboo FYI - I decided to look at this problem more, because it was interesting.  I will share some of my findings soon.  Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, the message should be contained by the QR not the image, if you diff the images from your solution, only the first line of pixels (of the 390x390 image) get changed and that data will be lost if noise is applied (as shown in the figure 12). The other error is that you are assuming that the QR can be damaged equally on all the parts, for example, if the position part is damaged as much as the data can tolerate, the QR will not be detected.

The paper does not give an example but it simplifies to `Damaged_QR = QR ⊕ String` assuming that *1 pixel = 1 cell*, in python it is a bit more involved as you can't easily xor raw buffers, for that 2 functions are needed to expand the bits of a string to a list of bools and viceversa.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import qrcode

def str_to_bool(text, char_bits=8):
    ret = []
    for c in text:
        for i in range(char_bits):
            ret.append(ord(c) & (1 << i) != 0)
    return ret

def bool_to_str(bool_list, char_bits=8):
    ret = ''
    for ii in range(len(bool_list) // char_bits):
        x = 0
        for i in range(char_bits):
            if bool_list[ii * char_bits + i]:
                x |= 1 << i
        if x != 0:
            ret += chr(x)
    return ret

def matrix_x_y(matrix, off_y_h=10, off_y_l=10):
    for y in range(off_y_h, len(matrix) - off_y_l):
        for x in range(len(matrix[y])):
            yield x, y
```

To add the message it's as simple as xoring a segment of the data of the QR, here a char is 8 bits, but it can be compacted to 5 if only upper case text is needed.

```py
original_data = 'Text' * 10
original_secret = 'Super Secret !!!'

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
)
qr.add_data(original_data)
qr.make()

original = qr.make_image()
original.save('original.png')

cursor, msg = 0, str_to_bool(original_secret)
for x, y in matrix_x_y(qr.modules):
    qr.modules[y][x] ^= msg[cursor]
    cursor += 1
    if cursor >= len(msg):
        break

modified = qr.make_image()
modified.save('modified.png')
```

To get the data back the QR needs to be read and re-created without the *"damage"* to then xor those two to get the data that can be converted back to a string.

```py
decoded_data = pyzbar.decode(
    Image.open('modified.png')
)[0].data.decode('utf-8')

redo = qrcode.QRCode(
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
)
redo.add_data(decoded_data)
redo.make()

nums = []
for x, y in matrix_x_y(qr.modules):
    nums.append(qr.modules[y][x] ^ redo.modules[y][x])
    
decoded_secret = bool_to_str(nums)
```

Then just verify that it worked, if QR gets actual corruption the message will get corrupted too and depending on how much error margin is left the QR might not even be readable.

```py
diff = ImageChops.difference(
    Image.open('original.png'), 
    Image.open('modified.png')
)
diff.save('diff.png')

print('Valid QR: {0}'.format(
    original_data == decoded_data
))

print('Valid Secret: {0}'.format(
    original_secret == decoded_secret
))
```

To the naked eye there is no difference from the original (the first one) and the other one, if you just want to use this as a water mark there is no need to obfuscate the data.
[image: Example out images]

Comment: The OP used the term "watermark" incorrectly.  That is not what the paper [Steganography of Encrypted Messages Inside Valid QR Codes](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8985346).

Comment: I know, a better term would be something like "hidden metadata"; i asume OP is interested in the embedding process only.

Comment: I'm still studying this problem for my own knowledge.  Your water marking technique is very solid.  Embedding a message is far more complex and that is what I'm burning cycles trying to figure out.  I'm upvoting your answer because it works.

Comment: So far the only issue that I have found with your marking technique is requiring the original image to decoded the modified image.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: No, you need both images (in matrix form), i guess the issue comes from the reading the matrix with the message, there is no library that returns the matrix as read (as far as i know) but you can make a variant of the decoder that does by removing without [this](https://github.com/dlbeer/quirc/blob/master/lib/decode.c#L922) line; another option that you can use is to correct the read image and overlap it with the new one, then resize down both to make each cell a pixel and the treating the pixels as a matrix but this might not be that consistent.

Comment: The issue with requiring the original image is that it must be passed in some way to the other party for decoding.  I thought about embedding it, but that has other security issues.

Comment: There is no need to pass the image, creating a new qr with the same data and correction level results in the same qr generation as the original therefor the modified qr can create the original qr.

Comment: So are you saying that the modified qr image can create the original qr image?  How is this even possible?

Comment: Because the algorithm that generates the qr has no random component, if the data and the parameters doesn't change, the result should be the same; the error correction part guarantees that you have the original qr, [here](https://github.com/dlbeer/quirc/blob/master/lib/decode.c#L922) you can see that the correction is before the read, meaning that the decode is on the original qr.

Answer (score -2):

The root of the problem was that the image was being saved as BW, which would round my encoded message to either 0 or 255, effectively throwing away any useful data.

By converting the images to grayscale, this allowed me to preserve the information. Some padding, and other matrix magics were applied as well. The whole solution cleaned up is posted here for future reference

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import qrcode
from PIL import Image


def create_qr_code(public_info, filename):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, box_size=10, border=5)
    qr.add_data(public_info)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    img.save(filename)


def encode_secret(qr_code_filename, secret_bytes):
    qr_image = Image.open(qr_code_filename).convert("L")
    qr_array = np.array(qr_image)
    secret_array = np.frombuffer(secret_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)
    secret_size = secret_array.shape[0]
    qr_size = qr_array.shape[0] * qr_array.shape[1]
    if secret_size > qr_size:
        raise ValueError("Secret message is too large for the QR code.")
    elif secret_size < qr_size:
        pad_size = qr_size - secret_size
        secret_array = np.pad(secret_array, (0, pad_size), mode="constant")
    secret_array = secret_array.reshape(qr_array.shape)
    result_array = qr_array ^ secret_array
    result_image = Image.fromarray(result_array, mode="L")
    return result_image


def read_qr_code(filepath):
    image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    qr_codes = pyzbar.decode(image)
    if qr_codes:
        qr_code = qr_codes[0]
        value = qr_code.data.decode("utf-8")
        return value
    return None


def decode_secret(encoded_image_filename):
    encoded_image = Image.open(encoded_image_filename).convert("L")
    public_info = read_qr_code(encoded_image_filename)
    if not public_info:
        raise ValueError("Missing Public info on QR Code")
    qr_code_filename = "pure_qr_code.png"
    create_qr_code(public_info, qr_code_filename)
    qr_image = Image.open(qr_code_filename).convert("L")
    encoded_array = np.array(encoded_image)
    qr_array = np.array(qr_image)
    secret_array = encoded_array ^ qr_array
    secret_bytes = secret_array.flatten().tobytes()
    return secret_bytes


def main():
    public_info = "25.61795.?000001?.907363.02"
    qr_code_filename = "qr_code.png"
    secret_message = b"this is a secret"
    encoded_image_filename = "encoded_image.png"

    create_qr_code(public_info, qr_code_filename)
    encoded_image = encode_secret(qr_code_filename, secret_message)
    encoded_image.save(encoded_image_filename)

    decoded_secret = decode_secret(encoded_image_filename)
    print("Decoded Secret Message:", decoded_secret[: decoded_secret.find(b"\x00")])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I don't believe that this answer is what the [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8985346) was proposing.  Read SECTION III. The Proposed System